# websource to ready excel

Tags: excel, web, powerquery, worksheet

from this webpage, if I want to fetch all the updates into a ready excel https://www.medsafe.govt.nz/other/Updates-Data-sheets-and-CMIs.asp.

As you can se the data is divided based on dates, and when I use 'get data' from excel option (from web) (power query), the data gets loaded into different worksheets based on dates. I want it in single excel one below other, and be differentiated by adding column beside which has the date, and by putting filter on date I can see the products. Please suggest a better way.

Also, as a seperate question, is there a faster way to collate data from multiple worksheets into single worksheet

Also, as a seperate question, is there a faster way to remove filter on all worksheets once, like ctrl+shift+L on all worksheets at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One question per question.

You can paste this into home...advanced editor... in powerquery

```
let Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.medsafe.govt.nz/other/Updates-Data-sheets-and-CMIs.asp")),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(Source[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Data", List,List)
in #"Expanded Data"
```

2. Yes
3. Yes

Comment: Thanks. Please share the way for question 2. and 3.  @horseyride. Also please let me know where can i type the above code